# Write $x^2+y^2=25$ as a vector valued function

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, parametric

How can I write $x^2+y^2=25$ as a vector valued function? At first, I tried letting $x=t$. Then, $y=\pm \sqrt{25-t^2}$.

So, $r(t)=t \hat{i}+ \sqrt{25-t^2}\hat{j}$

Would this be correct? What happens to the $\pm$?

Comment: You want a parametrization? It's a circle with radius 5, try $x = 5\cos t$ and $y = 5\sin t$.

Comment: It is an equation, not a function. Moreover both members of the equation are scalars, not vectors. Maybe you want an equation for the same set in terms of the vector $\binom xy$; that still would be an equation, and it still would be scalar valued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r(t)=5\cos t \hat{i}+5\sin t\hat{j}$, where $0\leq t < 2\pi$